# How can I make a StreamReader Open/Read/Close process into a function

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I frequently use a StreamReader to iterate over files and read/manipulate text.  Instead of constantly having to type a script similar to:

```
## StreamReader setup / file availability check

try {
    ## Create Stream Reader
    $readStream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($Path)

    ## Do stuff ...

} finally {
    $readStream.close()
}
```

How can I make the entire setup/open/close process into a function that I can call whenever I need to automate the 'Do Stuff' portion of my above code?  I am aware of how to make functions but I cant figure out how to turn this into a usable function so I only have to write it and edit it once but can use many times.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it does work.

You have different Functions for each type of processing I just called my test Process-Stream.

```
Function Process-Stream {

  Do {
  
    $Line = $readStream.ReadLine()
    "$Line"
  
  } While ($readStream.EndOfStream -eq $False)

} #End Function Process-Stream
```

Next you have a function that does all of your setup and error processing for the Stream.

```
Function Get-Stream {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
      [String] $SourcePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
      [String] $ProcessFunction
  )
  
  try {
      ## Create Stream Reader
      $readStream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new(
         "$SourcePath")
  
      & $ProcessFunction
  
  } finally {
      $readStream.close()
  }
  
} #End Function Get-Stream
```

Now you just call Get-Stream with the name of your processing function.

```
PS> Get-Stream -SourcePath "G:\Test\StreamIOTest.txt" -ProcessFunction Process-Stream
Line 1 
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4

PS>
```

Note: the test text file I used had 4 lines. Don't forget you need to have the functions loaded!

Updated: I realized after I posted that I should have parameterized the file to be read and passed that into Get-Stream also.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to process your text files *line by line*:

There's no need to deal with `[System.IO.StreamReader]` instances directly - you can use PowerShell's built-in features.

- In the simplest case, if performance isn't paramount, combine [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

  ```
  Get-Content $Path | ForEach-Object { <# Do Stuff with $_, the line at hand #> }
  ```
- When performance matters, use a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) with the `-File` parameter:

  ```
  switch -File $Path { Default { <# Do Stuff with $_, the line at hand #> } }
  ```